# Wesite responsivo - Como jogar a div para baixo

Tags: css, div, float, media-queries

Olá, pessoal! Peço ajuda com o seguinte problema:
Sou voluntária na área de desenvolvimento de websites e preciso deixar meu website responsivo, pois muitos idosos estão acessando via celular.
Tenho 2 Divs principais onde se encontram os conteúdos. Para que sejam exibidas lado a lado na tela de um computador/notebook, estou usando o float:lef; float:right no CSS, mas no celular gostaria que a div da direita migrasse para baixo. Já tentei de várias formas e elas fazem um overlapping. As width já estão configuradas em porcentagem pra que o código possa funcionar (não estão com valor fixo).

Alguém tem ideia do que falta?

#content            {   width:50%; float:left; margin-top:15px; }
#rightside          {   width:40%; float:right; margin-top:15px; }

Estou utilizando as queries abaixo e esperava que fossem solucionar, mas não parecem funcionar.

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
/* For mobile phones: */
.content {
width: 100%;
}
}
.rightside {
width: 100%;
}
}

Answer (score -3):

Seria bom você usar o display: flex;
na div que está os #content e o #rightside
você adiciona:
flex-direction vai organizar do lado ou em cima e embaixo e sapce-between vai deixar um em cada ponta

div {display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between;}
#content { width:50%; margin-top:15px; } #rightside { width:40%; margin-top:15px;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { /* For mobile phones: */ div {flex-direction: column}

Answer (score -3):

Você está colocando **id** para a versão "computador/notebook" e para "celular" usando **classes**.

***Você não pode usar id para a versão desktop e classes para a versão mobile, ou você usa id ou classes para todos.***

Na sua versão para celular sua classe ***"rightside"*** está fora da ***@media query*** então não funcionará.

===================================================

Tente assim:

Computador/Notebook

```
#content { ... } 
#rightside { ... }
```

Celular

```
#content { width: 100%; }
#rightside { width: 100%; }
```

===================================================

Adaptei seu código para isso:

```
#content {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#rightside {
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  #content {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #rightside {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Código completo aqui:

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-lichterman-ocb65v?file=/style.css:0-393